# How create pom file in android studio for artifactory?

Tags: android-studio, artifactory, aar

I have uploaded .aar without pom.xml to artifactory and thus cannot load the library using gradle.
I would be grateful if you tell me or show how it should look inside the pom.xml.
If someone knows how to create the desired content file, then it will be great.

I tried to create pom.xml using the code in gradle below, but it seems to me that this is the wrong option.

```
task writePom {
    doLast {
        pom {
            project {
                groupId 'com.someth.someth'
                artifactId 'name'
                version '1.1'
                url="http://someth.com/artifactory/someth_pr/someth-release.aar"
            }
        }.writeTo("pom.xml")
    }
}
```

I used url to show where to get my .aar file.

When I put my generated pom.xml file in artifactory and decided to do "Sync now" gradle gave an error:

> Failed to resolve: com.someth.someth:name:1.1

Answer (score 2):

From Android Gradle plugin 3.6.0 and higher you can use the `afterEvaluate{}` publishing which allows you to publish build artifacts to an Apache Maven repository. It includes all the components for each build variant artifact in your app or library module (with the generated pom.xml).
More info you can find in the [official Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin).

Have in mind that the repositories tag inside the pom.xml file (if you want to import dependencies from a custom source) it's skipped by the Android's gradle tasks for security reasons.

Last, you could use also the old classic way for the publication described by the [JFrog official documentation](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-publish-build-info-along-with-the-artifacts-into-artifactory-from-a-gradle-android-project/).